# Javascript function object body

Tags: javascript

If  in Javascript functions is objects(key/value pairs), can I think that function body stored in some property of function object?

Comment: Thanks everybody for replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could think of this that way. This was more formalized in the [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-types-of-source-code) spec:

> *Function code* is source text that is parsed to supply the value of the `[[ECMAScriptCode]]` and `[[FormalParameters]]` internal slots ([see 9.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects)) of an [ECMAScript function object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects).

and

> ECMAScript function objects have the additional internal slots listed in [Table 27](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#table-27)
>
> [...]
>
> `[[ECMAScriptCode]]` Parse Node   The root parse node of the source text that defines the function’s body.

An "internal slot" is basically like a property that cannot be accessed from user code, it cannot only be accessed by the runtime itself.

So yes, the function object has a reference to the (parsed) code of its body in some way.